# Update sequencial SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela `SGI01A` no meu banco, em que uma coluna de registros segue a seguinte lógica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em algum momento, essa ordenação saiu de ordem e começou a contar de forma "errada". O que era para ser `025/19` virou `031/19` e voltou para soma correta.

Como seria a query SQL correta para alterar todos esses valores de volta para a ordem à cima sem que precise mudar um registro por vez?

Comment: Você precisa de fato alterar ? Este valor é usado em outras tabelas ? Como esta sequencia é gerada ?

Comment: A intenção é alterar, esses registros só são escritos nessa tabela mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, acredito que o jeito mais fácil de fazer isso vai ser utilizando alguma linguagem de programação para poder comparar o valor anterior com o atual e ter um controle melhor dos dados.
Veja abaixo um exemplo de como fazer isso utilizando python:

```
import re
#Simulando o select com os dados do seu banco
valores = ['NIG-022/19','NIG-023/19','NIG-024/19','NIG-031/19','NIG-032/19','NIG-033/19']

sequencia = []
pattern = "(?<=NIG-)(.*)(?=/)"
# Utiliza expressão regular para extrair somente os números que devem estar em sequencia.
for atual in valores:
  x = re.search(pattern,atual)
  if x:
    sequencia.append(int(x.group()))

# Ordena a sequencia.
for i,numero in enumerate(sequencia):
#A partir da segunda posição compara se o numero atual é igual ao numero anterior +1, se não for, altera o mesmo para manter a sequencia.
  if i >0 and numero != (sequencia[i-1]+1):
    sequencia[i] = sequencia[i-1]+1

#Insere a sequencia ordenada nas strings
for i,atual in enumerate(valores):
  x = re.search(pattern,atual)
  if x:
    valores[i] = re.sub(pattern,str(sequencia[i]),valores[i])
#imprime as strings já ordenadas sequencialmente.
print(valores)

#Aqui você cria a lógia para dar update no seu BD.
```

Caso queira testar o exemplo acima, pode utilizar este [link](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/Python-testes)